# WebSphere Liberty Profile AdminClient coonection

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

For monitoring WebSphere application server via Perf Mbean 
    I have choose the either RMI or SOAP connector port to get connection from Adminclient. As following code describes,

```
Properties localProperties = new Properties();
localProperties.put("type", "RMI");// RMI or SOAP
localProperties.put("host", localhost);
localProperties.put("port", 2809);// connector port
AdminClient client = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(props);
```

So I need same for WebSphere Liberty profile 8.5. There is no detailed about admin console i cannot find the connector port details RMI or SOAP. How to configure or choose connector port and connect to adminclient as above code. what i do in server.xml to enable the RMI or SOAP port.

Answer (score 1):

Liberty doesn't have an admin client like you're using with traditional WAS.  You can use JMX to connect to and manage Liberty as explained in the [IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_serverconnection.html).  The list of available mbeans for Liberty can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_mbeans_list.html).